# Netlify triggered builds without any action from anyone in our team. Why?

Tags: git, deployment, netlify

My webapp front end is connected to Netlify to handle deployment. As it is supposed to work, each time someone merges something to master, staging or prod branches, Netlify automatically triggers the build for the deployment.

Nobody in the team did any commit nor triggered manually any build on Netlify, however this morning I saw that builds were triggered for my 3 main branches yesterday.

Does anyone has any idea about how this could have happened ?

Answer (score 4):

Note:  I work for Netlify.

Indeed, this was some fallout from [this incident](https://netlifystatus.com/incidents/2017/02/02/api-and-ui-downtime/).  Our CDN edge nodes ended up with some bad 404's cached and the easiest way to restore was to redeploy from that same build hash.  Super sorry that screwed up your site, Stan!

In general, the way we trigger git-backed deploys is via webhooks:  https://www.netlify.com/docs/webhooks/#incoming-webhooks - but the "default" webhook is setup automatically when you link a repository with us during setup.  You can remove this webhook to stop us from being notified of commits which is what triggers builds.

The notifications were real and the rebuilds intentional, though unasked-for by you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug Netlify had yesterday. As for our case, our webapp and its various branches have not been affected by that. However, here are couple of consequences we had as a result of that bug:
 - all the previous triggers from January have been overwritten by the re-triggered builds (builds history has changed)
 - re-triggers have been made in the wrong chronologic order, so all our previews don't match with our most recent code (after talking with Netlify team)

Don't hesitate to complete/approve that list if you've experienced same/other stuff.